# Find application root URL without using ~

Tags: asp.net

I need to construct the URL of a page in a String, to send it an email (as part of an email verification system). If i use the ~ symbol to denote the app root, it is taken literally.

The app will be deployed on a server on three different sites (on different ports) and each site can be accessed via 2 different URLs (one for LAn and one for internet).

So hardcoding the URL is out of question. I want to construct the url to verify.aspx in my application

Please help

Comment: Are you going to be sending out a different URL if they are inside the LAN, or do you want it to be the same URL?

Comment: It would help to see the actual code how you're attempting to construct that string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the methods listed generated the full url starting from http://---.

So i had to extract these from  request.url. Something like this

```
Uri url=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
urlString.Append(url.Scheme);
urlString.Append("://");
urlString.Append(url.Authority);
urlString.Append("/MyDesiredPath");
```

Can someone spot any potential problems with this?

Answer (score 13):

You need this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
```

It's equivalent to "~" in a URL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx

Comment: ApplicationPath doesn't produce a URL that is usable in an email. For an email, you would need the full URL, complete with "http://.../" etc. ApplicationPath would only give you "/".

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
string url = req.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped)
    + ((req.ApplicationPath.Length > 1) ? req.ApplicationPath : "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the URL as part of your web application's configuration. The web application does not know how it can be reached from the outside world.

E.g. consider a scenario where there's multiple proxies and load balancers in front of your web server... how would the web server know anything but its own IP?

So, you need to configure each instance of your web application by adding the base URL e.g. as an app setting in its web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpRequest.RawURL` (docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_properties.aspx))property and base your URL on that, but if you are behind any kind of redirection, the RawURL may not reflect the actual URL of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this. I take the request url, and use the position of Request.ApplicationRoot to discover the left part of the uri. Should work with applications hosted in a virtual directory "/example" or in the root "/".

```
    private string GetFullUrl(string relativeUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relativeUrl)) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("relativeUrl");

        if (!relativeUrl.StartsWith("/"))
            throw new ArgumentException("url should start with /", "relativeUrl");

        string current = Request.Url.ToString();
        string applicationPath = Request.ApplicationPath;
        int applicationPathIndex = current.IndexOf(applicationPath, 10, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        // should not be possible
        if (applicationPathIndex == -1) throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to derive root path");

        string basePath = current.Substring(0, applicationPathIndex);
        string fullRoot = string.Concat(
            basePath,
            (applicationPath == "/") ? string.Empty : applicationPath,
            relativeUrl);

        return fullRoot;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has always worked for me:

```
string root = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "");
```

Comment: Please see [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) questions on SO.

Comment: I didn't understand the downvote. Anything wrong with the suggested solution?